# Overriding jboss security domain for a Jersey REStful service

Tags: java, security, jersey, jboss5.x

We have an application which uses Jersey RESTful web services to communicate with the frontend.  The services are secured with SPNEGO, so running on JBoss 5, we have a SPNEGO security domain configured.   However, for a couple web services, the client is not the front end but non-Windows clients (hence SPNEGO will not work).  I would like to override the security domain with a BASIC auth scheme for these services.  I am searching for a way to do this preferably without Spring Security (this is not in our technology scope).  But if it has to be Spring Security, so be it.  I am looking for a way to do this with annotations if possible.